# adding a column to sqlalchemy db after init with flask

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

i had a the following code:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class story(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc= db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, desc):
        self.desc= desc
```

and i created the db in a different file.

after the db table was created i needed to add another column to the db, so
i added the following code to the "Text" class:
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

but when im running the project it output the following error:

OperationalError: (OperationalError) table story has no column named name

my question is: how can i change the db after it already been created?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alembic for "automatic" migrations

http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Or just add the new column to the database yourself

alter table STORY add column name ....